# Linear Algebra - Real Matrix and Invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}$ be a real matrix $2n\times 2n$ with $A,B,C,D$ real matrices $n\times n$ that are commutative to each other. Show that $M$ is invertible if and only if $AD-BC$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try considering
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
D(AD-BC)^{-1} & -B(AD-BC)^{-1} \\
-C(AD-BC)^{-1} & A(AD-BC)^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. Now I feel dumb I wasn't able to answer this on my linear algebra test -,-

Comment: @FadhlyL This is the “if” part; but I think you can also do the “only if”.

Comment: Can't the "only if" part simply be proven by the fact that the inverse of a matrix is unique? Or does it require further work?

Comment: @FadhlyL No. You have to assume $M$ is invertible and to argue that $AD-BC$ is as well